# Truth table and the meaning of $\oplus$ in propositional logic

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus

Could someone show me the truth table for this proposition? I think I have the last two down, but I'm not sure what the symbol in the following one is:
$$p\oplus (p\wedge q)$$

Comment: The symbol is for [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Answer (score 2):

The first symbol that appears in called "exclusive OR" or also known as XOR

XOR will evaluate to false when both values are True, or both values are false.

$$ \begin{array}{cc|c} p & q & p \oplus q \\ \hline
T & T & F \\ 
T & F & T \\
F & T & T \\
F & F & F \end{array} $$

Answer (score 1):

$p\oplus t$ is true only when exactly one of $p$ and $q$ is true, knowing this we construct the table in the following way:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        p & q & p\wedge q & p\oplus (p\wedge q) \\
        T & T & T & F \\
        T & F & F & T \\
F & T & F & F \\
F & F & F & F \\
        \end{matrix}
$$